# CMD removes spaces when using and (i.e. "cmd /C ... && ...")

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I use the `cmd` command with two actions anded together, the spaces are removed from the second action and then doesn't run correctly. When I run

```
C:\>cmd /C "set "MYVAR=MYVAL" && echo %MYVAR%"
```

I expect

```
MYVAL
```

But I get

```
'echo%MYVAR%' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
%MYVAR%
```

Why is this happening?

## UPDATE

I have figured what is causing the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

I created a batch file I called `.cmdrc.bat` that runs whenever I open a new cmd window. Effectively giving me custom functions and aliases with `DOSKEY`. This was causing problems with programs that launched their own cmd window, so I tried to detect if cmd was opened with a program or by the user, and then only run if a user launched it.

To do this I stripped spaces and quotes from `%COMSPEC%` and `%CMDCMDLINE%` and compared them. But for some reason, this appears to be changing the value of `%CMDCMDLINE%` to the version without spaces, causing the original issue.

Here is the relevant code:

```
:: only run this script if cmd.exe was launched by the user and not a program
:: this is done by checking if this prompt was launched with options

:: get the command that user would run and remove any spaces or double quotes
set cmdloc=%COMSPEC%
set cmdloc=%cmdloc: =%
set cmdloc=%cmdloc:"=%
:: get the command that was run to launch this instance and remove any spaces or double quotes
set cmdcall=%CMDCMDLINE%
set cmdcall=%cmdcall: =%
set cmdcall=%cmdcall:"=%
:: now compare them and exit if they are not the same
if /I not "%cmdloc%" == "%cmdcall%" (exit /B)

:: no flags were used when launching this instance of cmd.exe,
:: assume it was launched by the user and run all following commands
```

Why is `%CMDCMDLINE%` updating with the new value?

What is a better way to detect if the user launched cmd?

Comment: when I execute it, the output is just `%MYVAR%`([as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082))

Comment: also - what program are you launching this batch file with? if you're just running a batch file there's no need for the extra `cmd` stuff at all.

Comment: @meal' I'm just running the command in cmd. I'm not currently launching it from a program or in a batch file.

Comment: try throwing it in a batch file (I added that to my answer) and see if you get the same error

Comment: try to use the preferred syntax for your `set` commands (like `set "cmdcall=%CMDCMDLINE%"` etc).

Comment: Are you sure that you really use `set cmdcall=%cmdcall: =%` and not `set cmdcall=%cmdcmdline: =%`, because the second variant would change the content of cmdcmdline. The cmdcmdline variable is the only one that will be changed by using string manipulation expressions!

Comment: @Stephan Ok, I added quotes around each set command and now it prints `%MYVAR%\nMYVAL`. Why is it printing `%MYVAR%` at all?

Comment: @jeb I pasted the actual code that I'm running.

Answer (score 1):

You need another `cmd /C`:

```
cmd /C "set "MYVAR=MYVAL" && cmd /C "echo %MYVAR%"
```

You can add/subtract quotes from the second command and it still seems to work.

or try throwing it in a batch file:

```
@echo off

set "MYVAR=MYVAL"

echo %MYVAR%

pause
```

Reference: [cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: I ran the command as you typed it, but I still get the same error. However, it does print `MYVAL` at the end instead of `%MYVAR%`.

Comment: interesting solution (although working, not quite correct -see my answer) - haven't seen that so far.

Comment: @TrevinAvery How do you execute it? It works for me (directly on command line)

Comment: @Stephan I opened a new cmd window and pasted it in exactly as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

The whole line is parse at once, so `echo %MYVAR%` echoes the value of `%MYVAR%`*before* setting the variable (resulting in an empty variable - therefore the output is a literal `%MYVAR%`. You need delayed expansion to make it work:

```
cmd /v:on /c "set "MYVAR=MYVAL" & echo !MYVAR!"
```

Another way to go is to implement a second layer of parsing with:

```
cmd /C "set "MYVAR=MYVAL" & call echo %MYVAR%"
```

or even with:

```
cmd /C "set "MYVAR=MYVAL" & cmd /C "echo %MYVAR%""
```

(thanks @mael', I haven't seen this solution so far)

(the double double-quote at the end is actually correct. It's `cmd /c "command line"`, where `command line` is `set "MYVAR=MYVAL" && cmd /C "echo %MYVAR%"`)

Note: `&&` works as "if previous command (`set`) was successful, then". Here a simple `&`("and then") is sufficient.

Comment: Should `cmd /C "set "MYVAR=MYVAL" & call echo %MYVAR%"` not actually read `cmd /C "set "MYVAR=MYVAL" & call echo %^MYVAR%"` in order to work even when `MYVAR` is already defined (given that `^MYVAR` is not, of course)? (and the same also for the `cmd /C` solution)